# How to exclude the "target" folder from ArchUnit tests

Tags: java, junit5, archunit

I have a test class that contains multiple ArchUnit rules, including the GeneralCodingRules provided by ArchUnit. However, I want to exclude the target folder from being considered during the ArchUnit tests since it's generated by the build process and not part of my source code.

Is there a way to globally exclude the target folder from my ArchUnit test class without having to define a rule for each exclusion manually? I'd like to ensure that ArchUnit doesn't analyze or report violations in the target folder. Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

I am Using ArchUnit JUnit 5 - Version 1.1.0

I'm aware that ArchUnit's @AnalyzeClasses annotation allows me to configure the packages for analysis, but I couldn't find a direct way to exclude specific directories like the target folder from the analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a custom [ImportOption](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/blob/main/archunit/src/main/java/com/tngtech/archunit/core/importer/ImportOption.java) to exactly control which classes you want to import.
(The linked source code shows some examples, e.g.`class DoNotIncludeTests implements ImportOption`.)

However, be aware that ArchUnit (currently) only analyzes byte code (i.e. `.class` files, no `.java` files). So if you don't want to consider anything in your `target` folder (I assume that this is from a Maven build, isn't it?), I wonder what you want to consider at all?